# My SQL script to decrypt data encrypted by EF Core

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core, aes

I have some of columns encrypted by ef core:

```
        var keyBase = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        var key = Convert.ToBase64String(keyBase);
        _provider = new AesProvider(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
        modelBuilder.UseEncryption(this._provider);
```

For testing purposes i want to decrypt it by sql script

```
SET @keyBase = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
SET @encrypted_data = 'some encrypted data from column';

-- Decode the keyBase from Base64 encoding
SET @key = UNHEX(@keyBase);

-- Generate a random IV (Initialization Vector) or use a predetermined one if available
SET @iv = UNHEX(SHA2(UUID(), 128));

-- Decrypt the data using the key and IV
SET @decrypted_data = AES_DECRYPT(FROM_BASE64(@encrypted_data), @key, @iv);

-- Return the decrypted data
SELECT CAST(@decrypted_data AS CHAR) AS decrypted_data;
```

Unfortunately this returns null

Comment: @Charlieface I do not see any custom functions. C# code contains standard crypto library references, mysql code contains standard mysql functions. Syntax is mysql.

Comment: The C# code converts the key to base64, whereas the mysql code converts from base64, although unhex is not exactly converting from base64. Also, you have to check if the two AES providers are compatible in the first place.

Comment: @Charlieface there are not custom functions expect standard one. Also this is MySQL script i run on MySQL Server. Sorry but why upvoted yours answers.

Comment: Well `-- Generate a random IV (Initialization Vector)` why are you using a random IV rather than the original

Comment: @Shadow what do you mean by " AES providers are compatible" i thought they must use same algorithm

Comment: One uses IV the other does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is answer

```
SET @keyBase = 'xxx';
SET @encrypted_data = 'xxx';

SET @@SESSION.block_encryption_mode = 'aes-256-cbc';

-- Convert the keyBase to binary
SET @keyBaseBinary = CONVERT(@keyBase USING utf8);

-- Convert the binary keyBase to Base64
SET @key = TO_BASE64(@keyBaseBinary);

-- Decode the keyBase from Base64 encoding
SET @binary_encrypted_data = FROM_BASE64(@encrypted_data);

-- Extract the first 16 bytes from the decoded data as the IV
SET @iv = SUBSTRING(@binary_encrypted_data, 1, 16);

-- Remove the IV from the binary data
SET @data_without_iv = SUBSTRING(@binary_encrypted_data, 17);

-- Decrypt the data using AES_DECRYPT in MySQL
SELECT CAST(AES_DECRYPT(@data_without_iv, @key, @iv) AS CHAR) AS decrypted_data;
```